# Replace white space with underscore and make lower case - file name

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am renaming files and directories. Basically, all I want to do is strip out spaces and replace them with underscores and finally make lower case. I could do one command at a time: `$ rename "s/ /_/g" *` , then the lower case command. But I am trying to accomplish this all in one line. Below all I am able to accomplish is strip out the spaces and replace with `_` but it doesn’t make lower case. How come?

```
find /temp/ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g; s,,?; ‘
```

Original file name:

```
test FILE   .txt
```

Result: (If there is a space at the end, take out)

```
test_file.txt
```

Comment: If you want to translate all ' ' to '_' and all letters to their lowercase counterparts, then `rename -n 'y/A-Z /a-z_/'` seems like the way to go to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rename 's/ +\././; y/A-Z /a-z_/'
```

Or, combined with `find`:

```
find /temp/ -depth -name "* *" -exec rename 's/ +\././; y/A-Z /a-z_/' {} +
```

To target only files, not directories, add `-type f`:

```
find /temp/ -depth -name "* *" -type f -exec rename 's/ +\././; y/A-Z /a-z_/' {} +
```

#### Shortening the names

> Would it be possible to rename the file with the last three characters
>   of the original file for example from big Dog.txt to dog.txt?

Yes.  Use this `rename` command:

```
rename 's/ +\././; y/A-Z /a-z_/; s/[^.]*([^.]{3})/$1/'
```

Comment: Perfect, I just realized that, I only want to target files and not directories.

Comment: would it be possible to rename the file with the last three characters of the original file for example from `big Dog.txt` to `dog.txt`?

Comment: Great! I have another question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218569/strip-whitspace-and-make-lower-case-up-to-hyphen-filename

Comment: If you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227758/while-loop-through-file-names-and-remove-white-space

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
echo "test FILE  .txt" | tr A-Z a-z | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '_'| sed 's/_\./\./'
```

Answer (score 0):

While the original question mentions using [`rename`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) explicitly, I am using macOS which does not have `rename` installed by default.

So instead I created this `find` script that uses the one-liner that Kristijan Iliev posted previously in [their 2014 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26208171/117259). It uses `tr` and `sed` so it is more portable across different Linux-like operating systems.

This simple script will rename relevant filenames in the current working directory; change the `.` to match a file path if desired.

```
find . -depth -name "* *" -type f |\
  while read source_filepath
  do
    destination_filepath=$(echo "${source_filepath}" | tr A-Z a-z | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '_'| sed 's/_\./\./');
    mv -f "${source_filepath}" "${destination_filepath}";
  done
```