# Strip whitspace and make lower case up to hyphen - filename

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, filenames, rename

I have a lot of text files which I am renaming with a specific format. Below I am able to remove whitespaces and make lower case. However, it is not the desired outcome.

How would I be able to format(take out spaces and make lower case) everything up the hyphen and then take only the first white space after the hyphen?

```
find /temp/ -depth -name "* *" -type f -exec rename 's/ +\././; y/A-Z /a-z_/' {} +
```

Input Result:

```
Hello Video - KEEP.txt
```

Output:

```
hello_video_-_keep.txt
```

Desired result:

```
hello_video_-KEEP.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was a file I would use:

```
sed -re 's/^([^-]*)-\s*([^\.]*)/\L\1-\U\2/' -e 's/ /_/g' file
```

- `s/^([^-]*)-\s*([^\.]*)/\L\1-\U\2/` converts to lowercase everything from the beginning of the file up to a dash `-`. Then it converts to uppercase up to the dot.
- `s/ /_/g` converts all spaces into underscores `_`.

For your given text it returns:

```
hello_video_-KEEP.txt
```

---

If you want to keep the word as it is from the `-` up to `.`, use `\E` to restore the case. Then, we can also get rid of the superfluous `_-` by replacing it to just `-` (a bit ugly, I know).

```
$ cat file
Hello Video - KEEP.txt
My File - KeEp.txt
$ sed -re 's/^([^-]*)-\s*([^\.]*)/\L\1\E-\2/' -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/_-/-/g' file
hello_video-KEEP.txt
my_file-KeEp.txt
```

As a reminder, these are the ways to change the upper/lower case:

- `\L` - convert all proceeding characters to lowercase
- `\U` - convert all proceeding characters to uppercase
- `\E` - leave all proceeding characters in their current case

---

How can you mark it work? Loop through the results of the `find` command:

```
while read -r file
do
   new_file=$(echo "$file" | sed -re 's/^([^-]*)-\s*([^\.]*)/\L\1\E-\2/' -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/_-/-/g')
   echo "mv '$file' '$new_file'"
done < <(find . -type f ...)
```

For the given input this will produce this content:

```
mv './My File - KeEp.txt' './my_file-KeEp.txt'
mv './Hello Video - KEEP.txt' './hello_video-KEEP.txt'
```

once you are sure it works, just remove the `echo` and use `mv` alone. Note the quotes are necessary!! Otherwise it won't handle properly the spaces in the file names.

Comment: Great but almost there. But anything after the `-` up to the `.` i want to leave it untouched and only remove the first whitespace after `-` from `My File - KeEp.txt` `my_file-KeEp.txt`

Comment: Perfect, great explanation. How would i run this on all file names in the directory `temp`? use for loop?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student as it is a `sed` with different parts, you could create a temp file with the output of your `find`, then apply this `sed` to it and finally execute it.

Comment: Oh I am little lost know. Not so familiar with the script syntax. But this is not working `sed -re 's/^([^-]*)-\s*([^\.]*)/\L\1\E-\2/' -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/_-/-/g' find /temp/ -depth -name "* *" -type f rename -exec`

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student it was a bit complicated... I just updated with a proper explanation. I hope it helps.

Comment: Great, it all makes sense now. Thank you for the well explained answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62528/discussion-between-code-ed-student-and-fedorqui).

Comment: is that the full `find` command `(find . -type f ...)` or is that indication that i need to finish that line? I am not close to cmd line to test

Comment: One extra thing, it doesnt seem to work with replacing lower case a file name like this `my File_pass - forBidden.txt` it just does thigs `my_File-forBidden.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\L` to convert to lowercase:

```
rename 's/ +\././; y/ /_/; s/(.*?-)/\L$1/'
```

- `s/ +\././` removes one or more spaces before a dot
- `y/ /_/` changes all spaces to underscores
- `s/(.*?-)/\L$1/` captures everything up to the first dash and lowercases it.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it explained what all the stuff in front of `\L` is for.